# Circuit Problem

Tags: circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

RT = R6 + [ R5 || ( [R1||R4] + [R2||R3]) ] = 7.2 KOhm

IT = 8 / RT = 1.11mA

I2 ( current through R5) =  (It Rt') /R5 where Rt' is everything excluding  R6

My question is what is the easest way to solve for I1. My assumption for Vab is that I could do a voltage divider for the voltage across R2||R3. thank you for the corrections!

Comment: (It Rt') /R5 is wrong ,it is  (It Rt') /(R5+Rt')

Comment: @Anklon Rt' = RT - R6. so OP is correct..

Answer (score 3):

Voltage across \$R_1\$,
$$V_{R_1} = I_TR_T'\times\frac{R_1||R_4}{R_1||R4 + R_2||R_3}$$
Then current through \$R_1\$,
$$I_1 = \frac{V_{R_1}}{R_1}$$

Since you have already calculated the values of \$I_TR_T'\$, \$R_1||R4\$ and \$R_2||R_3\$ the calculations would be easy.